# Eclipse JDK8 to JDK11 Issue: Package is accessible from more than one module

Tags: java, debugging, java-8, java-11

- Error after changing Java from Java 1.8 to Java 11.
  The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml.
- Module path is not used.
- below class files are imported, but errors occurring

1. import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
2. import org.w3c.dom.Document;

- The package javax.xml is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You have libraries on your classpath which provide packages which are already provided by Java itself, in this case `org.w3c.dom`. Remove those libraries (or upgrade to a version which no longer includes those packages). If you use a modular project, Java doesn't allow split packages at all, if you don't use a modular project, Java doesn't allow split packages for packages which are part of the Java runtime (the classpath is essentially treated as one module, which can't split packages with modules of Java itself).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.